# In Classroom in Google Drive, view only one assignment in a class of 2 or more assignments

Tags: google-drive, google-classroom

I am regularly setting classwork with Google Classroom. I may give two pieces of work shared with "make a copy for each student". I then want to monitor students work during the lesson, however I am not interested in one of the pieces of work at this time. How can I see just the assignment that I am looking for (for all students).

**Some ideas:**

An option to put the assignments in sub-folders would help. I could write a script for this, but it would have to run after the class starts, and before I start assessing. So not practice, unless it can run on a trigger.

Filtering, maybe there is an option to filter the results. But when I use the search it finds stuff from outside of the current folder. (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

When in google drive, right-click on the directory in the bread-crumbs, there is an option `search within zzzzzz`, where `zzzzzz` is the name of the folder that you clicked. It also works if you right-click the folder name in a directory listing.